# Creating a concurrent/parallel ForEachAsync that can fail immediately or wait until enumeration is complete

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library

I needed an asynchronous parallel `ForEach` mechanism so I could enumerate an enumerable by N degrees of concurrency and process an action for each item.  Searching around, my code was modeled/merged from a few posts I found.

The tests I have been running are:

1. Run `body()` to completion
2. Inside the `body()`, do a `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`
3. Inside the `body()`, throw a `OperationCancelledException()`
4. Inside the `body()`, throw a `NotSupportedException()`

First, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877042/166231) points to a Stephen Toub post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/).  I came up with combination of Toub's methods to have `maxDegreeOfConcurrency` and exception options (following bits from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849661/how-to-make-task-waitall-to-break-if-any-exception-happened))..

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body, AsyncParallelOptions parallelOptions )
{
    ConcurrentBag<Exception> exceptions = null;

    var maxDegreeOfConcurrency = parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism;

    // If they pass in a CancellationToken from caller of ForEachAsync need to create linked token source in case caller cancels, I want
    // ForEachAsync to cancel as well.  If they want to failImmediately, make a new CancellationTokenSource so I can stop processing partitions
    var cts = parallelOptions.CancellationToken != null ? CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource( parallelOptions.CancellationToken ) :
              parallelOptions.FailImmediately ? new CancellationTokenSource() : null;

    var allDone = Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create( source ).GetPartitions( maxDegreeOfConcurrency )
        select Task.Run( async delegate
        {
            using ( partition )
            {
                while ( ( cts == null || !cts.IsCancellationRequested /* either from caller or failImmediately */ ) && partition.MoveNext() )
                {
                    await body( partition.Current )
                    .ContinueWith( t =>
                        {
                            // If body() threw an error, cancel if a CancellationTokenSource is present.
                            if ( t.IsFaulted )
                            {
                                if ( parallelOptions.FailImmediately )
                                {
                                    cts.Cancel();
                                }

                                // Always gather the exception to throw at the end
                                if ( exceptions == null ) exceptions = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();

                                foreach ( var ex in t.Exception.InnerExceptions )
                                {
                                    exceptions.Add( ex );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                }
            }
        }, cts.Token ) );

    // Wait until all finished (or errored out) and then return exceptions
    await allDone;

    // Question: allDone is never going to have IsCanceled or IsFaulted correct?  because await body() will swallow all exceptions?
    Console.WriteLine($"ForEachAsync Extension: Check Exceptions, {exceptions?.Count ?? 0} total, allDone.IsCanceled: {allDone.IsCanceled}, allDone.IsFaulted: {allDone.IsFaulted}, cts.IsCancellationRequested: {cts.IsCancellationRequested}" );

    if ( exceptions != null )
    {
        throw new AggregateException( exceptions );
    }
    else if ( cts.IsCancellationRequested )
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Reading and conforming to.  Sorry.

Comment: Revised code and new questions at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145326/concurrent-parallel-foreachasync-proper-handling-of-exceptions-and-cancellatio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `CancaellationToken` is a struct, not a class, so it can never be null. When people don't want to cancel stuff they just pass `CancellationToken.None`.
2. However note that If you change your `cts` assignment logic to something like `parallelOptions.CancellationToken != CancellationToken.None` you could hit a `NullReferenceException` when the cancellation token is None and `FailImmediately` is false. One simple way to make things work would be to just always assign `cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(parallelOptions.CancellationToken)`. Then you won't need the `cts` nullity check in the loop as well.
3. Instead of checking for `IsCancellationRequested` directly, it's a better practice to call `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` - that way you will actually mark the task as canceled.
4. Instead of checking `t.IsFaulted`, it's a better practice to check if `t.Exception != null`.
5. Instead of iterating over `t.Exception.InnerExceptions`, you should iterate over t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions`.
6. Creating the `ConcurrentBag` inside the task like you're doing now is not thread safe. I suggest just creating it upon declaration (instead of assigning null like you do now).
7. `allDone` issues:

   1. `allDone` could be faulted if one of the `body` methods throw *synchronously*.
   2. `allDone` would have IsCanceled set if cancellation was initiated either by the caller or by the `FailImmediately` logic
   3. In either case, you won't get to the following line as `await allDone` would throw.
8. You don't need `else` after you `throw new AggregateException`.
9. If all you do is re-throw the exceptions at the end of the method, you could just `await` the `Task.WhenAll` and get the same behavior for free (without the `Console.WriteLine` though). To make this work, you'll have to re-throw the exception instead of adding its inner exceptions to the concurrent bag.

Comment: Revised code and new questions at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145326/concurrent-parallel-foreachasync-proper-handling-of-exceptions-and-cancellatio.